# AWS API Gateway Model Validation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am developing an API on the AWS API gateway. I am using the model validation option to validate the JSON payload. Changing the model schema does not take effect immediately. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: What do you mean by 'immediately'? You mean you change the model schema and then deploy, and at that point you would like it to take effect immediately?

Comment: My apologies, I might have missed re-deploying the API. I re-deployed and its trying to validate the request but I am getting back an "invalid request body" below is my serialized Json    {"carrier": "dfdfdf", "payload": "dfdfdf", "encryptionPassword": "dfddfd"}          and below is my schema

Comment: {
    "title": "Person",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "carrier": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "payload": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "encryptionPassword": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "required": ["carrier", "payload"]
}

Comment: nevermind, I tried to send a post request from postman and it works fine. Looks like there is a problem with my python code. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sorry for the back and forth, but, I added another model with API validation enabled and it is not getting recognized. The problem I am experiencing is that when I add a new model, enable API validation and re-deploy the API, those changes does not take effect immediately. If I send a request using the new model I get an invalid body error for a few hours before it starts working.